# How to scrape page with chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I am making a chrome extension and I wanted to know if there is a way I can scrape information from a webpage and fill that information in a text field.

Comment: Please provide more info, like what information would you like to scrape, links, titles?

Comment: i want to get email, first name, last name and number.